# How can I change geoserver style content?

Tags: php, geoserver

This is my geoserver style `test.sld` file content.
Example

```
<sld:NamedLayer>
  <sld:Name>Test</sld:Name>
   <sld:UserStyle>
    <sld:Name>Test</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>Test</sld:Name>
          <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Test>
        <sld:Test>
          <sld:CssParameter name="fill">##939A94</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Fill>
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#939A94</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Stroke>
```

How can I change this content in php curl commands?
Put xml content.I want know geoserver edit style sumbit button api.

Comment: cross posted https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259452/how-can-i-change-geoserver-style-content

Answer (score 1):

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) provides a [REST API](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/) to allow you to carry out administrative tasks including adding a [style](http://docs.geoserver.org/api/#/1.0.0/styles.yaml).

If you want to add the SLD file then you `POST` the file to the `/styles` endpoint, you can also use `GET` to retrieve an existing style to modify and then `PUT` the changed file back.

You may also need to `POST` an xml file to `/rest/layers/{layer}/styles` to add a style to a layer. For example, this XML will create a style called `roads_style` on the layer using the `roads.sld` file that was uploaded earlier.

```
<StyleInfoPost>
    <name>roads_style</name>
    <filename>roads.sld</filename>
</StyleInfoPost>
```

Comment: I dont wont to update through roads.sld file. I want to update through content.I get .sld file content to geoserver and show my page,and when I change file content and submit button,I want to update this content to geoserver.

Comment: You must upload the new style as an SLD and then associate it with the layer.